# How can I search for longest substring in a more efficient way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, time-complexity, substring

I'm trying to search for the longest substring in a string, in linear time. How can I do this without using the max function?

This is the question:

> Given a string, find the length of the longest substring without
> repeating characters. Can you find a solution in linear time?

And this is my solution:

```
class Solution:
  def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, sentence):

     evid = []
     word = ''

     for i in sentence:
      if i not in word:
        word += i
      else:
        evid.append(word)
        word = ''
        word += i

     return len(max(evid, key=len))

print(Solution().lengthOfLongestSubstring('abrkaabcdefghijjxxx'))
```

Thank you!

Comment: 1. Maybe as you find each `word` you could compare its length with the previous longest. And 2. What if the string were `"abacdefghijlmnopqrstuvwxyzb"` - would your code find the string starting `b`?

Comment: @balmy Thanks for noticing! Fixed it :]

Answer (score 0):

You should not operate on strings when it comes to membership testing (`O(N)`). A truly linear solution would use a `set` and two pointers:

```
class Solution:
    def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, sentence):
        crnt = set()
        m = lo = hi = 0
        
        while hi < len(s):
            if (c := s[hi]) in crnt:  # membership check is O(1)
                # move lo past the most recent occurrence of c
                while (d := s[lo]) != c:
                    # removing all characters along the way
                    crnt.remove(d)
                    lo += 1
                lo += 1
            else:
                crnt.add(c)
                if len(crnt) > m:
                    m = len(crnt)
            hi += 1
        
        return m
```

As every index/char is added to and removed from the `crnt` set at most once with both operations and the contains-check all being `O(1)`, this approach is linear.

Comment: OP does ask rather vaguely about not using `max`. But you answer still includes `max`....?

Comment: Well, you don't want to call max repeatedly on a sequence of unknown length because of the O(n) performance. I call max on exactly two values all the time which has constant time complexity. I removed the `max` call though if that serves any more principled objections.

Comment: OP doesn't want to call `max` at all. Ah you've fixed it. All you've got to do now is get your code so it runs. `NameError: name 's' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

It can be done as follows:

```
def length_of_longest_substring(s):
    last_index = {}  # Dictionary to store the last seen index of each character
    start_index = 0  # Starting index of the current substring
    max_length = 0   # Maximum length of substring without repeating characters

    for end_index, char in enumerate(s):
        # If the character is repeated and its last seen index is after the start
        if char in last_index and last_index[char] >= start_index:
            start_index = last_index[char] + 1

        # Update the last seen index of the character
        last_index[char] = end_index

        # Update the maximum length if needed
        max_length = max(max_length, end_index - start_index + 1)

    return max_length

# Example usage:
input_str = "abcabcbb"
result = length_of_longest_substring(input_str)
print(result)
```